# Alternative for multicollinearity problem

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, multicollinearity, economics

I am a bit unsure how to specify my model and therefore look for some references / ideas.

I am interested in a model along the following lines:

$pay_i = \alpha + \gamma X_i  + \beta pop_i + \epsilon_i $

where $pay_i$ is the salary level of individual $i$, $X$ are some job specific controls, such as years in the company, and $pop_i$ is scale measuring the popularity among colleagues.

The problem is that $pop_i$ is driven by (correlated with) $X_i$ as, e.g. popularity grows over time. Therefore I have a multicollinearity problem. The VIF for $pop_i$ is not very high (around 2), however I am also interested in the following relation:

$pop_i = \delta + \omega X_i + \rho_i$

I have seen papers that argue the VIF is not high enough or some that would exclude $pop_i$. However, let's assume I know that $pop_i$ affects $pay_i$ and I am especially interested to examine both relationships.

Would you just run both models like this and argue with the low VIF or is there any other alternative modelling here (the adjusted R-squared for the second model is still 0.5)? I had a look, but don't have additional data for an IV.

Comment: so far you have not shown any evidence of multicollinearity problem. it is common for variables in X to be correlated with each other. this alone does not constitute a problem. you will probably have an endogeneity issue: it's likely that pay will impact popularity

Comment: Mhh so I actually run the second model first and find an adjusted R2 of 0.55. So you don’t think it would be an issue to present both models while arguing that the VIF is too small to be a problem here?

Comment: i don't take VIF seriously myself. R2 doesn't tell me much either, you can stuff up the model with regressors to inflate it as high as you wish